# ALAssetsLibrary.enumerateGroupsWithTypes first parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alassetslibrary

I try to use the `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` method of the `ALAssetsLibrary` class but I get an error with the first parameter.

### The method's prototype :

```
func enumerateGroupsWithTypes(types: ALAssetsGroupType,
    usingBlock enumerationBlock: ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock!,
    failureBlock: ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock!)
```

### How I call this method :

```
assetLib.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupAll, usingBlock: success, failureBlock: fail)
```

but I get a compile error `'CUnsignedInt' is not convertible to 'ALAssetsGroupType'`

### Other tests :

Based on what I've found on internet and my own tests, I've also tried

#### Test 1

```
assetLib.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupAll as ALAssetsGroupType, usingBlock: success, failureBlock: fail)
```

And the result is a compile error `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'ALAssetsGroupType'`

#### Test 2

```
assetLib.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupAll), usingBlock: success, failureBlock: fail)
```

And the result is a runtime error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and an XCode crash.

Comment: Isn't it an enum? If so, you need to pass in `ALAssetsGroup.All` or just `.All`.

Comment: It's not an enum as in Objective-C : `var ALAssetsGroupAll: CUnsignedInt { get }` `typealias ALAssetsGroupType = Int`

Comment: I see...looks like one of those cases where they used `enum` and not `NS_ENUM` and the translator broke...bug report!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the correct way is to use `ALAssetsGroupType`'s initializer to create a new `ALAssetsGroupType`. The following should work:

```
assetLib.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType(ALAssetsGroupAll), usingBlock: success, failureBlock: fail)
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to compile:

Although, it's untested as I don't know exactly what it returns with `allZeros`.

It may return `0x00000` as opposed to what you need, which is `0xFFFFFF`.

Still might be a good reference for people in the future.

```
let assetLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
assetLib.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupType.allZeros, usingBlock: { (results, stop) in
    println(results)
}, failureBlock: { (fail) in
    println(fail)
})
```

**EDIT:**

Well, what happens if you do the following?

```
assetLib.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(0xFFFFFFFF, usingBlock: ...)
```

I get the following:

```
(ALAssetsGroup - Name:Instagram, Type:Album, Assets count:46, )
(ALAssetsGroup - Name:Snapchat, Type:Album, Assets count:0, )
(ALAssetsGroup - Name:Camera Roll, Type:Saved Photos, Assets count:681, )
(nil, )
```

It's probably a bug like Jack Wu mentioned where they probably used `enum` and not `NS_ENUM` and the translator broke.

Doing this might be a workaround for the time being.

> Types of Asset
>
> **Constants to identify types of asset.**

```
enum {
   ALAssetsGroupLibrary        = (1 << 0),
   ALAssetsGroupAlbum          = (1 << 1),
   ALAssetsGroupEvent          = (1 << 2),
   ALAssetsGroupFaces          = (1 << 3),
   ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos    = (1 << 4),
   ALAssetsGroupPhotoStream    = (1 << 5),
   ALAssetsGroupAll            = 0xFFFFFFFF,
};
```

Comment: `ALAssetsGroupType.allZeros` return `0x00000` while the value of the option that I want to use is `0xFFFFFF`. So it compile but don't produce the expected result (none of the bit is set so the result will always be an empty array).

Comment: @Morniak See my updated answer. Have you tried `0xFFFFFFFF` as the `ALAssetsGroupType`?

Comment: Yes,it work and this is what I'm doing but it's not a viable solution. `0xFFFFFFFF` is a magic number and if for any reason apple change the values of this enum my app will be broken.

Comment: @Morniak: Yeah, that's correct. That is why I mentioned doing this might be a workaround for the time being.